# como se accede a un array de objetos en javascript

Tags: javascript, array

tengo este array

```
arrayAviones =[ { destino: { nombre: 'España', casos: 264 }, iDAvion: 'A-961' }
]
```

como puedo acceder a iDAvion

pongo esto

```
 arrayAviones[0].destino
```

pero me sale undefined

Comment: si haces un `console.log(arrayAviones[0].destino);` te devuelve `{casos: 264, nombre: "España" }`... si necesitas acceder a uno de ellos escribe `arrayAviones[0].destino.casos` o `arrayAviones[0].destino.nombre`.  Ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/bhz5ksp0/

Comment: Y para el iDAvion pon `arrayAviones[0].iDAvion`

Answer (score 2):

Estás accediendo de forma incorrecta a la propiedad. Tiene que acceder de la siguiente manera:

```
arrayAviones[0]["iDAvion"]
```

Comment: pero es que dentro de aviones no hay un array por que deberia usar la sintaxis []?

Comment: lo que quisiera es que me devolviera todos los id del avion

Comment: @anonymuus_gp la sintaxis de `[]` no es exclusiva de los Array, puedes acceder a las propiedades de un objeto con la notación de corchete también. Saludos

Comment: Si el array real es más grande y tienes repetido el iDAvion varias veces entonces debes recorrerlo con un bucle `for` y acceder a sus valores mediante arrayAviones[x]["iDAvion"] donde x es el número de iteración.  Una vez tengas eso los vas agregando a un array o un objeto y cuando termine el bucle ya lo tendras.

Answer (score 1):

Quizás esto te ayude a lo que quieres hacer :).

```js
var arrayAviones = [{
    destino: {
      nombre: 'España',
      casos: 264
    },
    iDAvion: 'A-961'
  },
  {
    destino: {
      nombre: 'México',
      casos: 345
    },
    iDAvion: 'B-576'
  }
];

var IDAviones = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayAviones.length; i++) { 
// recorremos el array con el bucle for() y así acceder a los object que contiene

  for (var key in arrayAviones[i]) { 
  // ponemos una variable en el for(), que accederá a las key (propiedades) de los objetos con 'in' más el objeto al que se quiere acceder 
  
    if (arrayAviones[i].hasOwnProperty(key) && key === "iDAvion") {
    // verificar si el objeto contiene esa propiedad con 'hasOwnProperty(valor)' y si la key es igual a iDAvion
    
      IDAviones.push(arrayAviones[i][key]); // agregamos el id al (array) IDAviones
    }
  }
}
console.log("#1 "+arrayAviones[0].iDAvion) // #1 forma de acceder directamente al valor del object dentro de un array

console.log("#2 "+arrayAviones[0]["iDAvion"]) // #2 otra forma de acceder directamente al valor del object dentro de un array

console.log("resultado :",IDAviones); // resultado: ["A-961", "B-576"]
```

Comment: si me ayudo, muchas gracias @Daniel